# Matching and updating two table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am going to fetch every row from one table and find the equivalent in another table. Then i am going to update the rows of the second table by using the id which i have already gotten.
I tried to run my script but i had some problems. 
I actually tried to make a loop and then put the id of every row in a variable to use them for my update statement but Pl shows me an error which tells me "not data found"

**My unfinished script**

```
DECLARE
tbl1Count number(4);
counter number(4);
MyO66ID number(8);
Begin 
 select  Count(*) INTO tbl1Count from crbank ;
 <<my_loop>>
 For counter IN 1..tbl1Count-1 Loop  
    select O66ID INTO MyO66ID  from crbank where rownum=counter;    
   End loop my_loop;
End;
```

Comment: you should include the ddls for both tables.

Comment: @OzgurBar what is the ddls  ?

Comment: I mean the structures (columns, column types if needed) to give the users an idea of the mentioned tables. like `tbl1(id,name,....,etc); tbl2(id2,name2,....,etc)`.

Comment: Why use a slow PL/SQL loop at all? This can most probably be done using a single SQL statement. Please show us the table definitions, some sample data and the expected result after the update. [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34736889/edit) your question, don't post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a strange logic in this scenario

**This should work:**

```
DECLARE
    tbl1Count number(4) :=0;
    MyO66ID number(8);
Begin 
    -- select Count(*) INTO tbl1Count from crbank; -- not needed at all

    For myItems IN (select O66ID, ROWNUM, whatever_columns_you_need from crbank) Loop  
        MyO66ID := myItems.O66ID;
        tbl1Count := tbl1Count + 1; -- this will serve you better than the first select if you are concerned of the number of rows you have.

        /*
          Do your logic here for the values you have in the myItems object
          EX: update yourTable set yourColumn = myItems.otherColumn where id= myItems.something
          You dont need variables to be defined if you noticed as in the above example.
        */


    End loop;
End;
```

**Hints:**

You are getting the `count`, then looping on the count you get and matching it with `rownum`!, which is not a best practice; hitting your database twice, for `count` and for `select`, although you can do it in once loop, and no need for the first select

`rownum` will be different for each select statement, depending on the order you specified, so is it wise to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned in your question

> *I am going to fetch every row from one table and find the equivalent in another table*

Oracle just have a workaround for this type of conditions. MERGE statement is very useful in these typical scenarios. Consider the below illustrated snippet. Let me know if this helps.

Whenever it is possible try to use pure SQL over PL/SQL

```
MERGE INTO <Update_table> USING <LOOKUP_TABLE>
ON 
(UPDATE_TABLE.COLUMN_NAME = LOOKUP_TABLE.COLUMN_NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
<UPDATE_TABLE.COLUMN_NAME> = <Update_value>
;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this one using cursor in sql.

Declare @id bigint

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR  

select data from table1

open CUR

Fetch next from cur into @id

while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
update table2 set columnname=value where id=@id
Fetch next from cur into @id
end

CLOSE CUR    
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Comment: This one seems SQL Server ? , cursor is also not advisable to use.

Comment: The question is about Oracle (PL/SQL), not SQL Server (T-SQL)